# Regex to select value in the URL with dashes (-)

Tags: html, regex, parsing

I have an URL as following:

http://www.working-test.com/first-second-third-star,**LG-Language-repeat,region-STATION-L-CITY**-residence.html#residence

with the Regex Pattern as following : http://regex101.com/r/hW9eK8

> `http://www\.working-test.com/first-second-third-star,(?<Host>[A-Z-.]+),(?<Host2>\w-?\w+)-(?<Host3>[A-Z-.]+)-residence\.html#residence`

I could match :

MATCH 1

Host    [52-70] `LG-Language-repeat`

Host2   [71-77] `region`

Host3   [78-92] `STATION-L-CITY`

But in the Host 2 sometimes, I have 1 or more than 2 dash (-) symbol like "region-A-B-C-STATION-L-CITY" , then the above pattern can't work.

So I wish to have in any case we can always separate the STATION-L-CITY as Host 3 with despite of how many dash(s) we have in Host 2 (region or region-A-B)

Thanks

Comment: How about ...`(?<Host3a>[^-]+)-(?<Host3b>[^-]+)-(?<Host3c>[^-]+)-residence`...?

Comment: @HannoBinder : Thanks but I want to keep host 3 with STATION-L-CITY at all time , here it took apart the Host 3 http://regex101.com/r/cR1uD2

Comment: `http://www\.working-test.com/first-second-third-star,(?<Host>[A-Z-.]+),(?<Host2>.+)-(?<Host3>[^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+)-residence\.html#residence`

Comment: @HannoBinder Thanks but it seems like the pattern has some errors

Comment: Dang! I'm sure it worked before I copied it over here and back. -- Somewhere in the process someone inserted "??" after `<Host2`, which are not displayed here :-\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the job: (Modified)

REference is here check:

[regex101.com/r/lZ5aM4](http://regex101.com/r/lZ5aM4)

Comment: Thanks but with your pattern the host3 is not STATION-L-CITY, I wish to keep host 3 as STATION-L-CITY at all time despite how many dash we have in host 2 . your pattern : http://regex101.com/r/lL8dJ7

Comment: Modified as per your comment, check now.

Comment: plz dont just link to external pages but include what is essential to answering the question in your post, too!

Comment: @SankalpBhatt : Thanks for your great answer but sometimes the Host 3 is also changed so if we put S as the beginning letter of Host 3 then if it is changed to another letter like HTATION-L-CITY then it doesn't work, sorry because I forgot to mention that http://regex101.com/r/bV1kU2

Comment: @user3520221 There should be something which seperates out HOST2 from HOST3. You need to give us that identifier then only we can help. In my code I used 'S' as that identifier.Try to analyze all the entries that you can have for HOST2 and HOST3 and figure out that identifier.

Comment: @SankalpBhatt : Yes thanks, actually the host 3 always contains 3 words which are separated by the dash, like FTROME-L-OURS or NAME-H-ODAS , could we have any other way to just get 3 last elements with dash for Host 3 ? Thanks

Comment: @user3520221 edited the link in answer so it points to correct link.